# getBytes then toString don't give the same result each time

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the sample BlueToothChat of Android but there is something I don't understand :

```
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", send.toString());
mChatService.write(send);
```

Here, message is a String, which is then converted to bytes, I guess in order to be sent. But When I check the log, the `send.toString()` part is really short even if the message I type is long. Worse, if I type twice the same message, I get 2 different logs, which is really weird I find.
Here is what I get in the log for the message `hello`, three times in a row :

```
[B@413d62e0
[B@41390078
[B@413ed3d8
```

There must be something (maybe really simple) I didn't get, but can(t figure out what it is. Can you help me with this?

Edit :
Maybe it is useful to add the following of the code, so here is the complete code :

```
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", send.toString());
mChatService.write(send);

// Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field (buffer is used in the write function)
mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
```

Comment: The default toString method returns getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, calling `toString()` on a byte array is a bad idea. Arrays don't override `toString()`, so you get the default behaviour of `Object.toString()`.

To reverse the `String.getBytes()` call, you want:

```
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", new String(send));
```

Or to see the bytes more directly:

```
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", Arrays.toString(send));
```

**However**, I would strongly encourage you *not* to do that directly. Instead, you should specify an encoding when you convert to or from binary, otherwise it will use the platform default encoding. What encoding is the chat service expecting? For example, if it's expecting UTF-8:

```
byte[] send = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", Arrays.toString(send));
mChatService.write(send);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new string object to get the actual string

```
String senddata=new String(send);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Log.d("SEND_BYTE", new String(send, "UTF-8"););
```